# SQL using MAX in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m trying to filter out reference numbers from one table based off an update date from another table. My query works but it is pulling back false hits because there are multiple update dates in the table. I’m trying to use the MAX value to only use the latest update date in my query but I can’t seem to get it to work:

```
select reference 
from active_table
where reference in (select reference from comment_table
                    where mod_date <= CONVERT (varchar, GETDATE() - 1 ,112))
```

Apologies for the formatting. Hopefully what I am after makes sense. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: What is the error message you get back?

Comment: Your `mod_date` is apparently a string. You should always select the correct datatype for the data you want it to hold. And you should **never** have a date as a string. And *if* you have to cast to a `varchar` you should **always** specify the length.

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask